# Will WinJS.UI.AppBar work on browsers?

Tags: winjs, appbar

I have used [WinJS](http://try.buildwinjs.com/playground/) and it works on Browsers. However, the WinJS site does not have examples for other controls like Win.UI.AppBar that can be used in Win8.1 or Win10.

Will [WinJS.UI.AppBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229670.aspx) work on Browsers and can be used for website development compared to windows store app development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use an AppBar on browsers. There no restriction to do that.

```
<div id="createAppBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{placement:'bottom'}">
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdAdd',label:'Add',icon:'add',tooltip:'Add item',section:'primary',type:'flyout',flyout:select('#addFlyout'),onclick:Sample.outputCommand}"></button>
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdRemove',label:'Remove',icon:'remove',tooltip:'Remove item',section:'primary',onclick:Sample.outputCommand}"></button>
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdEdit',label:'Edit',icon:'edit',tooltip:'Edit item',section:'primary',onclick:Sample.outputCommand}"></button>
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdCamera',label:'Camera',icon:'camera',tooltip:'Take a picture',section:'primary',onclick:Sample.outputCommand}"></button>
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdSettings',label:'Settings',icon:'settings',tooltip:'Settings',section:'primary',onclick:Sample.outputCommand}"></button>
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdShare',label:'Share',icon:'reshare',tooltip:'Share',section:'primary',onclick:Sample.outputCommand}"></button>
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdPrint',label:'Print',section:'secondary',onclick:Sample.outputCommand}"></button>
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdNetwork',label:'Network',section:'secondary',onclick:Sample.outputCommand}"></button>
```

You can find here the sample: http://winjs.azurewebsites.net/#appbar :)